Can I capture the value of 'value' attribute and save it as a variable?
I would like to capture the value of an input element and save it as a string variable in Robot Framework. How would I do this?
The element structure is as follows:
<input name="name" class="input" type="text" value="Default Text">

I would like to capture the "Default Text" value and save it in a string using Robot Framework and Browser Library.

Let's assume the xpath is as below:
//input[@name = 'name']

Then to get element attribute
${GET_ATTR_ELE}   Get Attribute    //input[@name = 'name']   value

where ${GET_ATTR_ELE} is the variable. 
Then set the variable to use it later
Set Test Variable    ${GET_ATTR_ELE}

Hope this helps!

OP explicitly has "robotframewok-browser" in the tags so question is not about Selenium.
